# YouTube Livestream API - Title required when title is provided

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, youtube-api, python-requests, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm trying to create a YouTube LiveBroadcast and a LiveStream in Python 3 using [Python Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). So far I've come up with this:

```py
# livebroadcast
data = {
    "kind": "youtube#liveBroadcast",
    "snippet": {
        "title" : str(channelName + " " + time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z", time.localtime())),
        "scheduledStartTime" : datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
    },
    "status": {
        "privacyStatus": "private"
    },
    "contentDetails": {
        "monitorStream": {
            "enableMonitorStream": False
        }
    }
}
r = requests.post("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts", headers=headers, params={"part":"snippet,status,contentDetails"}, data=json.dumps(data))

# livestream
data = {
    "kind": "youtube#liveStream",
    "cdn": {
        "format": "1080p",
        "ingestionType": "rtmp"
    },
    "snippet": {
        "title": str(channelName + " " + time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z", time.localtime()))
    }
}
r = requests.post("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveStreams", headers=headers, params={"part":"snippet, cdn"}, data=json.dumps(data))
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
{
    'error': {
        'code': 400,
        'errors': [{
            'reason': 'titleRequired',
            'extendedHelp': 'https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert#request_body',
            'domain': 'youtube.liveBroadcast',
            'message': 'Title is required'
        }],
        'message': 'Title is required'
    }
}
```

I don't see why I'm getting this error, because I'm specifying the title in both request bodies (or at least that's what I think I'm doing). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*Note: I cannot use [Google's API Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/) for various reasons*

Comment: If that is your error, then you must do this as per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#channelSections_youtube.channelSections.insert): "If the **`snippet.type`** property has a value of **`multiplePlaylists`** or **`multipleChannels`**, then you must set the section's title by specifying a value for the **`snippet.title`** property."

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 I believe I am supplying a title - in the `data` dictionary, I supply a `title` in `snippet`. What am I doing wrong? I can't seem to figure out